# Display Data Across Pages in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, ejs

Hi so I have an array of tons of users that I want to display.

How do I split them into different pages? Like page buttons to scroll through at the bottom.

Using Express and EJS.

Comment: What code do you have now?

Comment: Well nothing atm, I just wanted a way to do this since idk.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.